# Why my filter not to works when I retrieve a data extension?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions

I wrote a piece of code to retrieve a data extension, and though I added a filter, it still get all records, as following:

```
var mapTagsEmailDE = DataExtension.Init("MapTagsWithEmails");
var productFilter = {
                    LeftOperand: {Property: "Type", SimpleOperator: "equals", Value: "Product"},
                    LogicalOperator: "AND",
                    RightOperand: {Property: "Email ID", SimpleOperator: "equals", Value: "14053"}
                };
Write("productFilter ____ " + Stringify(productFilter) + "<br/>");
var mapTagsEmail = mapTagsEmailDE.Rows.Retrieve(filter);
Write("mapTagsEmail str = " + Stringify(mapTagsEmail) + "<br/><br/>");
```

The MapTagsWithEmails as following:

```
[{"Tagging Date":"12/8/2015 3:10:25 AM","Type":"Product","Tag Key":"Protamine Roche","Email ID":"14053"}, 
{"Tagging Date":"12/8/2015 3:10:25 AM","Type":"Indication","Tag Key":"Alzheimer's Disease","Email ID":"14053"}, 
{"Tagging Date":"12/8/2015 3:10:25 AM","Type":"Therapeutic Area","Tag Key":"Nervous System (ns)","Email ID":"14053"}, 
{"Tagging Date":"12/8/2015 3:10:25 AM","Type":"Product","Tag Key":"Neotigason","Email ID":"14208"}, 
{"Tagging Date":"12/8/2015 3:10:25 AM","Type":"Indication","Tag Key":"Chronic Hepatitis C","Email ID":"14208"}, 
{"Tagging Date":"12/8/2015 3:10:25 AM","Type":"Therapeutic Area","Tag Key":"Infectious Diseases","Email ID":"14208"}, 
{"Tagging Date":"12/8/2015 3:10:25 AM","Type":"Product","Tag Key":"Mericitabine","Email ID":"14246"}, 
{"Tagging Date":"12/8/2015 3:10:25 AM","Type":"Indication","Tag Key":"Influenza","Email ID":"14246"}, 
{"Tagging Date":"12/8/2015 3:10:25 AM","Type":"Therapeutic Area","Tag Key":"Infectious Diseases","Email ID":"14246"}]
```

Could you please explain this condition? Why and how to resolve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Small typo in your code, try to execute below code.

`var mapTagsEmailDE = DataExtension.Init("MapTagsWithEmails");
var productFilter = {
        LeftOperand: {
            Property: "Type", 
            SimpleOperator: "equals", 
            Value: "Product"
            },
        LogicalOperator: "AND",
        RightOperand: {
            Property: "Email ID", 
            SimpleOperator: "equals", 
            Value: "14053"
            }};
Write("productFilter ____ " + Stringify(productFilter) + "<br/>");
var mapTagsEmail = mapTagsEmailDE.Rows.Retrieve(productFilter);
Write("mapTagsEmail str = " + Stringify(mapTagsEmail) + "<br/><br/>");`